# A continuous function on a set that is bounded and has finite measure

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Define $H(x) =  \int_{X} \sin(xt) \,dt $ Show if $X$ is also bounded, then $H$ is differentiable. I have shown that $H(x)$ is continuous and was hoping I could use that somehow. I was thinking of using the monotone differentiation theorem to show $H(x)$ is differentiable but I would need to show that $H(x)$ is non-decreasing. $H(x+1) = \int_{X} \sin(xt+t) \,dt$ which just shifted the input to the left $t$-units. Then $H(x)$ could be larger than $H(x+1)$. So I thought what about showing the upper and lower derivatives are equal. I am using the definitions that lower derivative =$ \lim_{y\to x} \inf (H(y)-H(x))/(y-x)$ and the upper derivative = $ \lim_{y\to x} \sup (H(y)-H(x))/(y-x)$. I find it a little hard to get my hands dirty with these sups and infs. Would greatly appreciate help.

Comment: Differentiate inside the integral sign.  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Measure_theory_statement) for conditions that need checking to do that.  Since $X$ has finite measure and the integrand is bounded, the dominating function $\theta$ can be taken to be constant.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little more? $Sin(xt) \leq 1$ so $H(x) \leq \lambda(E)$. The link you sent has a measure theory statement part but it assumes the domain is open, which I do not have here. I am assuming that the constant function that will be dominating is $\lambda(E)$.

Comment: In the notation used by wikipedia, take $X:=\Bbb{R}$, $\Omega := X$ (your $X$), $f(x,\omega) := \sin(x\omega)$, $\theta(\omega)\equiv 1$ and $f_x(x, \omega):= \omega \cos(x\omega)$.  Then apply the measure-theoretic Leibniz rule.